# Combining distinct and annotate over a many to many filter with Django

Tags: django, many-to-many, distinct, annotate

With Django's ORM, I have a simple Question and Topic model like so:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Question(models.Model):
    topic_items = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, blank=True)
    date_asked = models.DateField()
```

Suppose I have four Questions asked each on separate dates, with the fourth sharing two topics 'topic1', 'topic2'

If I do the following query with topics_restrict a list of the two topic ids for 'topic1' and 'topic2'...

```
q_filter = Question.objects.filter(topic_items__in=topics_restrict).distinct()
```

Then I get four results (instead of five, which would have resulted without the distinct)

Now if I do the following:

```
    return q_filter.annotate(
        total=Count('date_asked')
    ).values_list('total', flat=True)
```

I get the result [2,1,1,1] instead of [1,1,1,1] - ie, as if the distinct() had never been applied.

The only way to get around it is to do...

```
q_filter = Question.objects.filter(pk__in=q_filter.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

... and then annotate on that q_filter.

But there has to be a better way?

Comment: It *is* applied, since the list contains *four* elements, not *five*.

Comment: The `.distinct()` is not put on the `topic_items`, but on the `Question`s after all.